# AIX filenames: unable to create directory with . (dot) sign in name

Tags: unix, console, cron, aix

Problem occurs when i try to create dir using `mkdir -p` command with . (dot) sign in directory name. When dot sign is removed from name, directory creates normally. But, if i'm not mistake, dot sign isnt forbidden for filename of unix-like systems. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know AIX, but agree that you can create a dir with a "." in the name (just tried on Mac OS X). Have you tried escaping the dot w/a backslash or putting it in quotes? +1 for AIX!!

Comment: Post the whole command you type and the error message you got. Also, what file system type is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "problem occurs" ?
Is there an error message, or is it just that you don't see the directory after creating ?

Be sure you browse your folder with a command that show the hidden folders like ls -a :-)

I don't know AIX either, so sorry if my answer is not accurate.

Comment: By "problem" i meant that dir was not created.

Comment: BTW, you right. There was my fault - dot sign means hidden folder. I dont knew this.